# Is there a (simple) way to update many documents in a mongo DB while changing the documents based on their current value?

Tags: mongodb

Basically, I want (**PSEUDO-Code**):

```
def getNewAttribute(based_on):
    return some_complex_operation_with(based_on)

ids = some_list_that_contains_ids_of_existing_documents
mongodb.some_documents.updateMany(
        {'_id': {'$in': ids}},
        { '$set': {'some_attribute': getNewAttribute(based_on=current_some_attribute_value)}}
    )
```

So, I do not want to update a document with some static new value but rather with a new value that depends on the old value **of that specific document**.

Comment: you can do it, using "$fieldName" references, using a pipeline update(like aggregation but update), as long as the operation can be done with aggregate operators. If not you still can using `$function` and javascript

Comment: @Takis_ I would rather stick to `$function`. It might be possible to go with `$fieldName`, but the complex operation is a lot of code and I'd like to keep it in one separate function. Could you give a small example how I can use `$function` there?

Comment: mongodb documentation is very good [for $function$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) , for [pipeline update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)